# Printing a python object doesn't yield the expected <__main__.myclass ...> output

Tags: python

When I create a Class like this

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

node = Node()
print node
```

prints `<__main__.Task object at 0x7fc9be21cd0>`.
However, I was using a library and wanted to print an object, which yielded the following:

```
foo.node(path="/test/1/2", value='Text')
```

how is this being constructed? value doesn't seem to be member variable or anything accessible? I was expecting something like `<__main__.foo object at ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was expecting a more explanatory answer, I found the answer in the Book "Fluent Python"  Basically the author of the library implemented the `__repr__`

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, path=0, value=0):
        self.path = path
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "foo.node(path="{0}", value='{1}')".format(self.path, self.value)
```

> The **repr** special method is called by the repr built-in to get string representation
>   of the object for inspection. If we did not implement **repr**, vector instances would
>   be shown in the console like `<Vector object at 0x10e100070>`

Answer (score 1):

It's generated by the [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method. And like all other normal methods, the instance it's being run on is passed as the first argument.

Comment: I'm intimidated by your points...so slowly asking...possible to generate a minimal example? never used `__repr__()` before